# Is there a way to swap between workspaces with a single key?

Tags: ubuntu, workspaces, ubuntu-mate

I would love to be able to swap between workspace 1 and 2 with a single key (like how alt+tab works with windows). I know CTRL+ALT+Arrow-keys works but a single key to switch between the two would be better.

I use Ubuntu MATE. Thanks in advance.
  Martin

Comment: You would consider alt+tab to be one key?

Comment: Do you? I said like how that works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. For anybody else who is looking to achieve the same, I set a shortcut key in "Keyboard Preferences" under "Switch to previously selected workspace".